# Get the unique exceptions and their count from the stack trace

Tags: java, pattern-matching, jsoup

I have an html file which contains the stack trace of the exceptions which occured during an execution. Now i want to get the exceptions from it and compare its stack trace for its further occurances. If the stack trace varies i increase it count.

Currently am using the jsoup parser to get the contents from the html file
How do i get the unique exceptions and their count. Attaching the code of what i have achieved so far

```
Elements elements = doc.body().select("pre");
    int index1 = 1;
    for (Element element : elements) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n" + links.get(index1).ownText());
        Elements a = element.children().select("li");
        boolean flag = true;
        for(Element b : a){
            exceptionText = b.ownText();
            Pattern patternExcpetion = Pattern.compile("(.+?) (.*Exception.*)");
            Matcher matcherException = patternExcpetion.matcher(exceptionText);
            if((matcherException.find()) && (flag == true)){
                System.out.println(matcherException.group(1));
                ExceptionList.put(matcherException.group(1).replaceAll("(:)"," "),0);
                flag = false;
            }
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^.*Exception.*$)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(exceptionText);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));    
            }
        }
        index1++;
    }
```

The sample HTML file

```
[8/5/2014 2:46:11 AM] [Error]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<boolean>false</boolean>
This exception was caught: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at VMware.vSphere.VimService.Login(ManagedObjectReference _this, String userName, String password, String locale)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereSession.Connect(String username, String password)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereHypervisorServiceProvider.GetComputeResources(ManagementEndpoint managementEndpoint)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereAgentService.GetHostClusterList()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.VRMCoreAgent.SendPingReport()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.CoreAgentBase.SendPingReportLoop(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)

[8/5/2014 2:47:16 AM] [Error]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<boolean>false</boolean>
This exception was caught: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at VMware.vSphere.VimService.Login(ManagedObjectReference _this, String userName, String password, String locale)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereSession.Connect(String username, String password)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereHypervisorServiceProvider.GetComputeResources(ManagementEndpoint managementEndpoint)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereAgentService.GetHostClusterList()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.VRMCoreAgent.SendPingReport()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.CoreAgentBase.SendPingReportLoop(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)

[8/5/2014 2:48:19 AM] [Error]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<boolean>false</boolean>
This exception was caught: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at VMware.vSphere.VimService.Login(ManagedObjectReference _this, String userName, String password, String locale)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereSession.Connect(String username, String password)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereHypervisorServiceProvider.GetComputeResources(ManagementEndpoint managementEndpoint)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereAgentService.GetHostClusterList()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.VRMCoreAgent.SendPingReport()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.CoreAgentBase.SendPingReportLoop(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)

[8/5/2014 2:49:23 AM] [Error]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<boolean>false</boolean>
This exception was caught: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at VMware.vSphere.VimService.Login(ManagedObjectReference _this, String userName, String password, String locale)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereSession.Connect(String username, String password)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereHypervisorServiceProvider.GetComputeResources(ManagementEndpoint managementEndpoint)
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.vSphere.VSphereAgentService.GetHostClusterList()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.VRMCoreAgent.SendPingReport()
   at DynamicOps.Vrm.Agent.Core.CoreAgentBase.SendPingReportLoop(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: first show us what your html looks like

Comment: @MaVRoSCy the html file
http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/480993/out_demworker_error_g1.html

Comment: Um, I don't want to enter my email address to download a file, can you edit it into your question, making it shorter if necessary ?

Comment: @JonasCz added some few some statements of my sample html file.

Comment: That does not really look like HTML to me, you might be better off processing it with a regex ?

Comment: the text is stored in the html file format. Anyways i found a workaround for my requirement using pyhton. Thanx for the response!